# Fetching the string from a variable in php?

Tags: php, scripting, curl

I have a variable $result in which fetched webpage contents are stored using curl. I want to search that variable or webpage and find the certain string say x and then store the next 5 lines in a new variable.

Can i do it in PHP ?

Thanks in Advance .......

Comment: `Can i do it in PHP ?` Yes sure you can !

Comment: Searching for a string within a string is easy - [`strpos()`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for example - but the difficulty here is how do you define `the next 5 lines`. And if you are with `fetched webpage contents` then a [DOM parser](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) is probably a better bet...

Comment: Sure you can!  Show us your first attempt, and we'll tell you how to improve your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find the position with strpos

```
$findme   = 'x';
$pos = strpos($result, $findme);
```

and then substr the result (not sure about linebreakes).

Or use regexp

Have a look here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: tonymarschall, I have tried and i am almost done with it . Now the main issue is that i have the starting point of string to be fetched but as the string to be fetched has dynamic length but the content after the string ends is same everytime . So what should i do to fetch it ?

Comment: If the string ends is defined, try to get startposition of string end. Then add strlength and use this with substr.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find the position of x in $resulst.

Afterwords you can start from that position, look for next 5 linebreaks in $result ('\n'), and build a new string.

This should work. Please try it on your own first. If you're having troubles with that, post the error and we can help you.

Comment: Johannes , I have tried and i am almost done with it . Now the main issue is that i have the starting point of string to be fetched but as the string to be fetched has dynamic length but the content after the string ends is same everytime . So what should i do to fetch it ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a scraping library like this one: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question changed, now you're looking for a string between two fixed characters(or strings).

```
<?php
$webpage_content = "Here
is
some text...
#000001 This is an Error code!
It can have multiple lines!
!content
This is normal content";


$start_element = "#";
$end_element = "!content";
$start_pos =  strpos($webpage_content, $start_element);
$en_post = strpos($webpage_content, $end_element);

$my_string = substr($webpage_content, $start_pos, $en_post-$start_pos);
print $my_string;
?>
```

You should have all information now, you need, to solve you problem. Please also read the links, we posted. PHP manual is available in more than 20 languages.